# Python installing module error

Tags: python, module

I installed this module

```
https://github.com/un33k/python-emailahoy/
```

using sudo

```
easy_install python-emailahoy
```

but if i runt his code i get this error

```
import sys
from emailahoy import VerifyEmail
e = VerifyEmail()
status = e.verify_email_smtp(
                    email='sss@sss.com',
                    from_host='mydomain.com',
                    from_email='verify@mydomain.com'
                )
if e.was_found(status):
    print >> sys.stderr, "Found:", status
elif e.not_found(status):
    print >> sys.stderr, "Not Found:", status
else:
    print >> sys.stderr, "Unverifiable:", status
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "email_script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from emailahoy import VerifyEmail
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/emailahoy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 46, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "/root/email_script.py", line 3, in <module>
    from emailahoy import VerifyEmail
```

How to fix and make that library working?

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: If that said something like `ImportError: No module named utils` - that mean you have other email module locally. And Python takes that one instead of the library.